# How to copy npm build artifacts from a docker container

Tags: docker, create-react-app

I have dockerized my CRA-bootstraped React app. I have no problems with running the dev server or tests in a Docker container. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]

CMD ["start"]
```

I would like to use Docker to produce consistent builds of my app - those generated by `npm build`.

When I run `docker run react-app build` the build is generated inside Docker container.

How can I make it so that the build artifacts are automatically copied to my machice? Most preferably to the current working directory.

Comment: you don't need copied artifacts, just use npm lock

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/?

Comment: @ZEE what do you mean by npm lock?

Comment: I'd just install Node, and `npm run build` on the host.  Why bring Docker into it?

Comment: @DavidMaze to ensure that the build output on a Ubuntu machine with Node 10 installed running on an AMD processor is exactly same as on a Windows machine with Node 15 with Intel CPU

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker volumes to map drive from your local machine to docker container and build the artifacts in the mapped location. This way you would be able to keep the artifacts on your machine.
[Docker Volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found out that using Docker volumes I can map (connect) `build` dir of a container to the local dir. The final command is as follows:

```
docker run -v ${PWD}/build:/usr/src/app/build -it react-app build
```

Hint: the path to the `build` directory in the container might be different if you're for example using different base image. I used the following command to enter the container and inspect the path:

```
docker exec -t -i <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash
```

Thanks @ashu for the hint leading me to the solution.